# IE 6 Table Row background colour?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

My CSS is supported in almost every browser out there, however IE 6 does not seem to want to give me the results I want.

http://99.241.156.130/?page=course

The table has stripes on them but for some reason in IE6, they appear with white gaps in between columns and rows.

Any helps would be great! :)

Comment: Rather than try to make it look exactly the same in IE6, accept that the site works correctly, looks adequate, and move on. IE6 is more trouble than it's worth (especially with Google soon discontinuing it), and your site (thankfully) doesn't have to look the same in every browser. /soapbox

Comment: Well, I am going for perfect, I only have issues with BSD OS browsers which no worries, most are in beta still. :)

Comment: I think you should install something like [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) on your site, and see just how many people are using IE6. For a high school site, I would expect the number to be below 2%, in this day and age. However, I will take a look at this, if you're super sure you want to invest time in IE6 support. Just say so (again).

Comment: It's good that you are a perfectionist but... http://dowebsitesneedtobeexperiencedexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example there are no css but you can make it easily by extra the code from the style tag. It's multi-browser portable.

```
<div align="center"><table id="myBoostTable" width="760" height="96" cellpadding="5" border="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-color:#000000;font-size:11px; border-collapse:collapse"><tr id="header"> <th align = "center" style="font-size:14px;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:700;font-style:normal;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top: 1px solid #000000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;border-left-color:#000000;border-left: 1px solid #000000;border-right-color:#808080;border-right: 1px solid #808080 " width="380"height="24" bgcolor="#EDEDF1"><font color = "#000000">This is my title col 1</font></th><th align = "center" style="font-size:14px;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:700;font-style:normal;border-top-color:#000000;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-top: 1px solid #000000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;border-left-color:#808080;border-left: 1px solid #808080;border-right-color:#000000;border-right: 1px solid #000000 " width="380"height="24" bgcolor="#EDEDF1"><font color = "#000000">This is my title col 2</font></th></tr><tr  > <td align = "left" style="font-size:12px;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;border-top-color:#000000;border-top: 1px solid #000000;border-bottom-color:#D3D3D3;border-bottom: 1px solid #D3D3D3;border-left-color:#000000;border-left: 1px solid #000000;border-right-color:#808080;border-right: 1px solid #808080 " width="380" height="24" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font color = "#000000">content 1-1</font></td><td align = "left" style="font-size:12px;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;border-top-color:#000000;border-top: 1px solid #000000;border-bottom-color:#D3D3D3;border-bottom: 1px solid #D3D3D3;border-left-color:#808080;border-left: 1px solid #808080;border-right-color:#000000;border-right: 1px solid #000000 " width="380" height="24" bgcolor="#F3EFFF"><font color = "#000000">content 1-2</font></td></tr><tr  > <td align = "left" style="font-size:12px;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;border-top-color:#D3D3D3;border-top: 1px solid #D3D3D3;border-bottom-color:#D3D3D3;border-bottom: 1px solid #D3D3D3;border-left-color:#000000;border-left: 1px solid #000000;border-right-color:#808080;border-right: 1px solid #808080 " width="380" height="24" bgcolor="#FAFAFF"><font color = "#000000">content 2-1</font></td><td align = "left" style="font-size:12px;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;border-top-color:#D3D3D3;border-top: 1px solid #D3D3D3;border-bottom-color:#D3D3D3;border-bottom: 1px solid #D3D3D3;border-left-color:#808080;border-left: 1px solid #808080;border-right-color:#000000;border-right: 1px solid #000000 " width="380" height="24" bgcolor="#EEEAFF"><font color = "#000000">content 2-2</font></td></tr><tr  > <td align = "left" style="font-size:12px;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;border-top-color:#D3D3D3;border-top: 1px solid #D3D3D3;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;border-left-color:#000000;border-left: 1px solid #000000;border-right-color:#808080;border-right: 1px solid #808080 " width="380" height="24" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font color = "#000000">content 3-1</font></td><td align = "left" style="font-size:12px;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;border-top-color:#D3D3D3;border-top: 1px solid #D3D3D3;border-bottom-color:#000000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;border-left-color:#808080;border-left: 1px solid #808080;border-right-color:#000000;border-right: 1px solid #000000 " width="380" height="24" bgcolor="#F3EFFF"><font color = "#000000">content 3-2</font></td></tr></table></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting gaps between columns and rows more than likely you have values in cellpadding and cellspacing. Setting both of those to 0 will remove the gaps.